# Select2 Use Array instead of Ajax Request with Templating

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I use Select2 and Ajax successfully to invoke the template command, but how do I change this to use the template command but remove the Ajax request i.e. use a array variable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $contact2 = $(".contact2");
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('/') }}' + '/api/opportunitycontacts/' + {{ $opportunity->id }},
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $contact2.select2({
                maximumSelectionLength: 1,
                data: data,
                templateSelection: function(result) {
                    return result['text'];
                },
                templateResult: function(result) {
                    if (!result['id']) {
                        return result['text'];
                    };
                    var final =
                        '<div>' +
                            '<strong>' + result['text'] + '</strong>' +
                            '<ul class="list-unstyled">' +
                                '<li><em>' + result['job_title'] + '</em></li>' +
                                '<li><em>' + result['facility'] + '</em></li>' +
                            '</ul>' +
                        '</div>';
                    return final;
                },
                escapeMarkup: function(result) {
                    return result;
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```